Filter keys in a list of dictionaries
I'm aiming to print a string, for example 'test', after the 'content' using python, but i have no idea how to do it. I already tried many pages talking about this, but nothing work.
mensagemmm = [ 
{'isUser': True,},  
{'isVerified': None,},  
{'isWAContact': True,},  
{'profilePicThumbObj': None,},  
{'content': 'Test',},  
{'quotedMsgId': None,} 
]
I already did try most of pages at google, using:
for i in mensagemmm...

Why is this structured like that in the first place? You've got a list of dictionaries, each containing only a single element.

This is a simplified structure of a whole page elements with one single element on different formats (str, int, bool...)

Check for content key then print the value
for i in mensagemmm:
  v = i.get('content')
  if v is not None:
    print(v)

If content key appears more than once in the list of dictionary, each would be printed

If your question is about how to access the string inside the dictionary, then
print(mensagemmm[4]["content"])  

returns 'Vai se fuder'
Or something like
print(list(mensagemmm[4].keys())[0],": ",mensagemmm[4]["content"])

which returns 'content :  Vai se fuder'
In other case please provide the expected output

The problem is, I need to access this item without knowing that it is in position [4]
